# Stopping Windows service asynchronously

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, service

I am trying to control a service within an application. Starting the service via StartService ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) works fine, the service needs about 10 seconds to start, but after calling StartService it gives the control back to the main-application immediately.

However, when stopping the service via ControlService ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682110%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) - AFAIK there is no StopService - it blocks the main-application for the complete time until the service is stopped, which takes about 10 seconds.

```
Start: StartServiceW( handle, 0, NULL)
Stop: ControlService( handle, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, status )
```

Is there a way for a non-blocking / asynchronously stopping of a windows service?

Comment: Did you try calling it from a thread? Classic approach to turning a blocking call into a non-blocking...

Comment: I do not know how but the `sc` command allows you to stop service without it being blocked on it. Try to look there for interesting API functions.

Comment: Is there one specific service that is behaving in this way, or all of them?  My guess would be that the service in question is not responding to the STOP request properly.

Comment: It is one service. The service takes about 10 seconds for cleanup / proper shutdown and during that time ControlService blocks. On the other hand the service takes about 10 seconds to start, but StartService does not block.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably look at stopping the service in a new thread. That will eliminate the blocking of your main thread.

Answer (score 1):

The SCM processes control requests in a serialized manner.  If any service is busy processing a control request, `ControlService()` will be blocked until the SCM can process the new request.  This is stated as much in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682108.aspx):

> The SCM processes service control notifications in a serial fashion—it
>   will wait for one service to complete processing a service control
>   notification before sending the next one. Because of this, a call to
>   ControlService will block for 30 seconds if any service is busy
>   handling a control code. If the busy service still has not returned
>   from its handler function when the timeout expires, ControlService
>   fails with ERROR_SERVICE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT.

Comment: Thanks, I already read that. There is no other control request except mine, so I don't think that this applies here, or?

Comment: "a call to ControlService will block for 30 seconds if **ANY** service is busy handling a control code", not just your service.

Answer (score 1):

The service is doing its cleanup in its control handler routine.  That's OK for a service that will only take a fraction of a second to exit, but a service that's going to take ten seconds should definitely be setting a status of STOP_PENDING and then cleaning up asynchronously.

If this is your own service, you should correct that problem.  I'd start by making sure that all of the cleanup is really necessary; for example, there's no need to free memory before stopping (unless the service is sharing a process with other services).  If the cleanup really can't be made fast enough, launch a separate thread (or signal your main thread) to perform the service shutdown and set the service status to STOP_PENDING.

If this is someone else's service, the only solution is to issue the stop request from a separate thread or in a subprocess.

Comment: Thanks. I'm already setting SERVICE_STOP_PENDING, but ControlService is blocking till SERVICE_STOPPED. Too bad ...

Comment: Is the service control routine exiting after setting the status to SERVICE_STOP_PENDING?  Can you show the code?